# Is there a way to easily get access to server from outside its network?

Tags: server, ip, ip-address, ipv6

I am running an old laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. I am trying to configure this as a server that I can access remotely. I have a static private ip address, but nota public one. My internet service provider does not support IPv6. Is there a way to easily access this computer from outside my network - I.e. assigning a public IP to it. I have tried many tutorials online - but are unable to find a way to do this.
I am quite new to dealing with servers, so could someone please walk me through this.

I have tried contacting the RIPE NCC database, but have not got anywhere. I have also tried using tunnelbroker - but again did not get anywhere.

Any and all help will be fully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to use a site to site VPN like wireguard.